# how to sum a collection after groupBy laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a  collection  named `detailed` as below :

```
Collection {#1421 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    3943 => Collection {#1419 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => RoomPricingHistory {#923 ▶}
        1 => RoomPricingHistory {#1042 ▶}
      ]
    }
    3944 => Collection {#1420 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => RoomPricingHistory {#1153 ▶}
        1 => RoomPricingHistory {#1264 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now i want to get the sum of RoomPricingHistory for `3943` item and `3944` ofc it can be more of 2 item so i want to get the sum of each collection how can i achieve that ??

Comment: what field of `RoomPricingHistory` do you need for the sum?

Comment: `sales_price` is what i need to sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Collection `sum` method can take a callback so you can define what is going to be calculated. In this case you can call `sum` on the main collection and in the callback which will give you access to the internal collections, also call `sum`.

```
$detailed->sum(function ($group) {
    return $group->sum('sales_price');
});
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `sum`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sum)

Since that isn't what you are looking for, you can use something like `mapWithKeys` to go through the collection and call `sum` for the groups to get the sum for each group:

```
$sums = $detailed->mapWithKeys(function ($group, $key) {
    return [$key => $group->sum('sales_price')];
});
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

Comment: cool but it gives me the sum for all 4 items i want 2 in 3943 and 2 in 3944 seperated is there any way ??

Comment: not a bug, i thought that was what you were asking for

Comment: i mean but sorry for that :)

Comment: Thanks sir that helped a lot , is there any way to push the values back into collection or should i ask another question to clearify that ?? :) thanks

Comment: how would you want the collection to look after that?

Comment: here take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138890/how-to-push-values-of-an-array-into-thier-own-item-of-object-in-laravel