# how to push values of an array into thier own item of object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have an object to return like below :
(the dd result)

```
Collection {#1421 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    3943 => Collection {#1419 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => RoomPricingHistory {#923 ▼
          #fillable: array:19 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "room_pricing_histories"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:26 [▶]
          #original: array:26 [▼
            "id" => 4132
            "accommodation_room_id" => 3943
            "net_price" => null
            "board_price" => null
            "foreign_board_price" => null
            "sales_price" => 4200000
            "extra_bed_price" => null
            "half_charge_price" => null
            "half_board_price" => null
            "full_board_price" => null
            "foreign_net_price" => null
            "foreign_sales_price" => null
            "foreign_extra_bed_price" => null
            "foreign_half_charge_price" => null
            "foreign_half_board_price" => null
            "foreign_full_board_price" => null
            "operator_id" => 11
            "commission_percent" => null
            "foreign_commission_percent" => null
            "discount_percent" => 10.0
            "foreign_discount_percent" => null
            "from_date" => "2019-05-25 00:00:00"
            "to_date" => "2029-08-30 23:59:59"
            "is_deleted" => 0
            "created_at" => "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            "updated_at" => "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
          ]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: array:1 [▶]
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
          #oldAttributes: []
        }
        1 => RoomPricingHistory {#1042 ▶}
      ]
    }
    3944 => Collection {#1420 ▶}
  ]
}
```

and i have some mapped data like below :

```
Collection {#1422 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    3943 => 8400000
    3944 => 400
  ]
}
```

now what i want to do is to return the mapped data which is the sum of price according to the id they have so the result of each item has the sum of price in it like below :

```
{
//room pricing history
 id:4132
room_id:3943
sum_of_prices :8400000
},
{
//room pricing history
 id:4133
room_id:3944
sum_of_prices :600
}
```

note : i am currently using resource but i dont know how to push the data in thier own object for example with this condition that they have the same id or something .

## UPDATE :

here is my method :

```
  $from_date = $request->get('from_date');
        $to_date = $request->get('to_date');
        $acc_id = $request->get('acc_id');
        $room_price = [];
        $period = CarbonPeriod::create($from_date, $to_date);
        $dates = $period->toArray();
        $room_ids = AccommodationRoom::where('accommodation_id',$acc_id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_ids); $f++) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {


                /****************************************
                 * Looping for the Number of Rooms User Given
                 *****************************************/
                $room_price[] = RoomPricingHistory::with('accommodationRoom', 'accommodationRoom.roomCapacityHistoryLast')
                    ->where('accommodation_room_id', $room_ids[$f])
                    ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$i])
                    ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$i])
                    ->get()->sortByDesc('created_at')
                    ->take(1);
            }
        }
        $room = collect($room_price);
        $room_collection= $room->flatten();
        $sums = $detailed->mapWithKeys(function ($group, $key) {
            return [$key => $group->sum('sales_price')];
        });
        return RoomDetailResource::collection($room_collection);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: sorry i will update the code too

Comment: dont know what 'id' would be in this scenario

Comment: @lagbox its the Id of room which is the same for two of them but the problem might be that the room is in the relation of pricing object which can make it harder

Comment: 923 is not the 'id', it is a number assigned to the object internally in PHP, the #923 is an identifier internally, it is not part of your Model ... otherwise I dont know where you got the 923 number from

Comment: @lagbox you are right sorry its a bit complicated to explain that #923 was the id of room_price which i fixed now so your right that should be pushed into room pricing object i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the previous question where we worked out how to get the sums of the groups we can expand on that to include any additional data you would like and use `map` instead:

```
$new = $detailed->map(function ($group, $key) {
    return (object) [
        'id' => $group->first()->id,
        'room_id' => $key,
        'sum_of_prices' => $group->sum('sales_price'),
    ];
})->values();
```

We throw the `values` call on the end to reset the keys so the JSON output would be an array not an object, and your example output didn't seem to use keys. If you still want these objects keyed by 'room_id' don't call `values`.

Though I am not sure what you are actually trying to do since any API Resource you have is expecting particular data. You seem to want to mix arbitrary data into Eloquent Collections.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. I totally missed he have array of price history in single item.