# Laravel Join, Sum, and Group by giving more value then expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

I am having an issue while getting result from the query in laravel. The query below is returning the sum of total boys and total girls more than expected. The relation of the Institute table has many Enrollments.

```
$dist_total_gender=DB::table('institutes')
    ->join('enrollements','enrollements.form_id', '=', 'institutes.form_id')
    ->groupby('institutes.district')
    ->join('Geographies','institutes.district', '=', 'Geographies.id')
    ->select(DB::raw("sum(enrollements.total_boys) as Total_Boys"), 
             DB::raw("sum(enrollements.total_girls) as Total_Girls"), 
             DB::raw("geographies.name as District"))
    ->get();
```

If Someone can write a query which will return exact sum of total boys and girls.

Comment: show your migrations. maybe you're using sum instead of count that's why probably

Comment: is there a date range? and year? or term? are you after the number of enrolments or the number of boys/girls (could this be different to enrolments?) in essence you haven't really given us much detail. sample data etc. would help  [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sum a collection after groupBy laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138254/how-to-sum-a-collection-after-groupby-laravel)